# Cloning a root partition onto a dm-crypt encrypted one

Tags: gentoo, encryption, dm-crypt, cloning

I have Gentoo Linux installed on a 25.93GB/62.43GB partition `/dev/sda4`.
The other partitions on the disk are 150MB `/boot` on `/dev/sda1` and 56,66GB unused space on other two partitions.

I am planning to encrypt the unused space with `dm-crypt`, format it to ext4 and after migrating my installation onto it, to nuke the old partition. My questions here are:

- Is this possible at all? Or would it require many tweaks to get the installation running on the encrypted volume `/dev/sda2`?
- Is this an efficient way? Taking into consideration my 25.9GB Gentoo, would it be less hassle for me if I just encrypted the   whole disk and installed Gentoo(and all the packages) again?
- Should I use `encfs` or `ecryptfs` instead of `dm-crypt` here? Would they provide equal security?
- What algorithm should I use to encrypt the partition? My processor does not have AES-NI.
- What should I use to sync the encrypted partition with the other one? Would something like `dcfldd` work for that?

---

Edit being written from migrated partition:

- After deleting the unused partitions and making a new unformatted `/dev/sda2`, I ran :

  ```
  cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 encrypt
  pv /dev/zero > /dev/mapper/encrypt
  ```

  `pv` here is used to monitor the progress of writing zeroes, and after this I formatted the encrypted partition to ext4 with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/encrypt`.
- To sync the partitions, I used YoMismo's recommendation `rsync` after booting the PC from a live USB. It didn't let me in with `chroot` though, I had to reboot my old partition and `chroot` from there instead. I ran in this process:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/old_partition /tmp/new_encrypt
  mount /dev/sda4 /tmp/old_partition
  mount /dev/mapper/encrypt /tmp/new_encrypt
  cd /tmp/new_encrypt
  rsync -av /tmp/old_partition/* .
  ```

  and after rebooting the old partition `/dev/sda4`, opening and mounting `/dev/sda2` and mounting virtual kernel filesystems:
- I made an `/etc/crypttab` with `root UUID=<uuid of /dev/sda2> none luks`
- I altered `/etc/fstab` to tell my root partition is `UUID=<uuid of mapper>`.
- I altered `/boot/grub/grub.conf` : I deleted `root=<root>` on the end of `kernel` line, and set a crypted device with `crypt_root=UUID=<uuid> root=/dev/mapper/root`.
- I ran `genkernel --install --luks initramfs` to make new initramfs with luks support.

Now I can boot and run it, the only thing left is setting the old partition on fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- Yes it is possible but you will have to do some tweaking.

2.- You can't encrypt the whole disk, at least boot partition must be unencrypted if you want your system to start (someone has to ask for the decryption password -initrd- and you need it unencrypted).

3.- `encfs` has some flaws, you can read about them [here](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm). I would use dm-crypt for the job.

4.- Can't help, maybe twofish?

5.- I would use a live CD/USB to do the job. I don't know if the space you have left is enought for the data on the other partitions, if it is (the partition is not full) I would:

- First you need to decide what kind of partition scheme you want. I will assume you only want /, /boot and swap. So /boot doesn't need to be messed with, I will also assume the space left in the unused partition is enough for the data you want to place in the encrypted partition (/ in this case).
- Start your system with the life CD.
- Assuming your destination partition is /dev/sdc1 do `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdc1` you will be asked for the encryption password. After that open the encrypted partition `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 Enc` write all zeros to it `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/Enc` and create the filesystem `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/Enc`
- Now mount your partition, copy files and change root to the new partition.

> `mkdir /tmp/O /tmp/D`
>
> `mount /dev/sda4 /tmp/O`
>
> `mount /dev/mapper/Enc /tmp/D`
>
> `cd /tmp/D;rsync -av /tmp/O/* .`
>
> `mount --bind /dev dev`
>
> `mount --bind /proc proc`
>
> `mount --bind /proc/sys sys`
>
> `mount --bind /sys sys`
>
> `chroot /tmp/D`
>
> `mount /dev/sda1 /boot`

-Use `blkid` to identify your partitions UUIDs and use that information to modify grub configuration files and your fstab (root partition device should be /dev/mapper/root_crypt). Modify your /etc/crypttab so that the new encrypted partition is referenced there. Create a line like `root_crypt  UUID=your/encrypted/dev/uuid none luks`. `grub-update` `grub-install` to where your grub must be and `update-initramfs` so that the new changes are updated in your initrd.

If I haven't missed anything you should now be ready to go unless you are worried about your swap partition, if you are and want to be able to resume from hybernation the you will have to follow the previous steps for encrypting swap partition and `mkswap` instead `mkfs.ext4`. You will also need to add the swap partition to the /etc/crypttab modify fstab so that /dev/mapper/name_swap_you_created_in_etc_crypttab is the device for the swap partition and `update-initramfs`.

Comment: Actually, one can use an [encrypted /boot partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Boot_partition) (on UEFI based systems, at least, though I do think it has to be separate from the whole / partition) with GRUB2

Comment: Encrypted /boot partition also works without UEFI, but you need to enter your decryption password twice. BTDT, and migrated back to an unencrypted /boot partition.